# Converting int to ASCII in C/C++

Tags: c++, opencv, path, ascii, yaml

I have a very simple problem in which i got stuck. Basically, I have an Alphabet database in which I want to access each letter one by one. For example, to access the image of letter A, I have to write -

```
ReadImg["A"] >> Letter;
```

I need all the letters to be scanned, therefore I will increment int x. The problem is in the ASCII conversion.  When I am putting a letter in the form of "(char)x", the compiler is looking at "(char)x" as (char)x instead of looking at it as a letter (e.g. 'A'). Can anyone point out a possible solution please?

```
void ReadDatabase(Mat &Letter, int x = 65)
{
    cv::FileStorage ReadImg("Alphabet.yml", FileStorage::READ);
    ReadImg["(char)x"] >> Letter;
    ReadImg.release();
    cv::namedWindow("Letter");
    cv::imshow("Letter",Letter);
    cv::waitKey();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try this:

```
ReadImg[string(1,(char)x)] >> Letter;
```

it will convert your variable `x` to a respective char and convert it to string..

Answer (score 0):

```
ReadImg[ cv::format("%c",x) ] >> Letter;
```